# How to get a "€" (u+20AC) character in a postgres UTF8 client encoding?

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, euro

I only found some strange results online where somebody tried `select E'\x020AC'`, `select E'\x020\x0AC'` or `select E'\x0AC\x020'` but none worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had to search and read more carefully in the [pg docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) and found the solution:

```
select U&'\20AC'  -- => "€"
select E'\u20AC'  -- => "€"
```